# Should we apply "noreferrer" on "Read More" or "View All"?

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers

I experienced years back a search engine crawler issue that Google started showing "Read More" as title of the page in it's search results. Because that page was linked through "read more" link on new blogs sections on homepage / search results with article title with link to full story, short desc and "read more" link to full story.

How to stop Google for recognizing "Read More" or "View all" as main keywords for the pages? As I think I can't apply "nofollow" even on read more to the indexable pages.

Homepage of my website contains "View All" link on the very first gadget linked to a page shows all jobs. And my main keyword for this page is "all govt jobs"

If we check blogger results, Google doesn't apply "read more" as a google practice. Just apply links to Titles for detailed story, so that story title must be same as of titles in the results.

But If I've a page which shows all results for a category type gadget e.g. Bank Jobs on homepage shows top 5 results with a reference "view all"